# Change WebView url from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, webview, appdelegate

I'm receiving notifications from Firebase in the AppDelegate class.
This notification contains a String named "notif_url". I've put this value in a var named "desired_url" and now I need to change my WebView url with the "desired_url" value.

But I can't access to the webview to change it url like this :

```
@IBOutlet weak var my_web_view: UIWebView!

func load_url(server_url: String){
    let url = URL(string: server_url);
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
    my_web_view.loadRequest(request);
}

load_url(server_url: desired_url);
```

Do you know if I can do that and if yes, how ?
Images :
[image]
[image]

**EDIT  1:**
After adding breakPoint to know the wrong line, it seem't that the line is this one :

```
my_web_view.loadRequest(request)
```

**EDIT 2:**
If need, that's a part of my AppDelegate class code.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    @IBOutlet weak var my_web_view: UIWebView!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){
        print("Step : 12");
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey]{
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        var url: String = userInfo[AnyHashable("url")] as! String;
        load_url(server_url: url);

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func load_url(server_url: String){
        /*
        let url = URL(string: server_url);
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
        my_web_view.loadRequest(request);
         */

        guard let url = URL(string: server_url) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        print("TRY : "+server_url);

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        my_web_view.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:**
If need, that's my ViewController class code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var my_web_view: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var my_loading_view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var spinner : UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var app_logo : UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var deadlinePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!

    var new_url: String = "";

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let server_url = "https://www.sortirauhavre.com/";

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
        rotated();

        spinner.startAnimating();


        my_web_view.scrollView.bounces = false;
        my_web_view.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true;

        let url = URL(string: server_url);
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
        my_web_view.loadRequest(request);
    }

    // CETTE FONCITON SE LANCE A LA ROTATION DE L'APPAREIL
    func rotated(){
        app_logo.center = my_loading_view.center;
        let y = app_logo.frame.origin.y;
        let h = app_logo.frame.size.height
        app_logo.frame.origin.y = y-(h/2);

        spinner.center = my_loading_view.center;
    }

    // CETTE FONCTION MET EN ARRIERE PLAN L'ANNIMATION DE CHARGEMENT
    func removeLoader(){
        self.view.addSubview(my_web_view);
    }

    // CETTE FONCTION MET EN PREMIER PLAN L'ANNIMATION DE CHARGEMENT
    func addLoader(){
        self.view.addSubview(my_loading_view);
    }

    // CETTE FONCTION SE DECLANCHE QUAND LES PAGES DE LA WEBVIEW COMMENCE A CHANGER
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        addLoader();
        let server_url = "https://www.sortirauhavre.com/";
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.removeLoader), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
        if let text = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString{
            if text.hasPrefix(server_url){
            }
            else if text != ""{
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: text)!)
                my_web_view.goBack()
            }
        }
    }

    // CETTE FONCTION SE DECLANCHE QUAND LES PAGES DE LA WEBVIEW FINI DE CHANGER
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        let server_url = "https://www.sortirauhavre.com/";
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.removeLoader), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
        if let text = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString{
            if text.hasPrefix(server_url){
            }
            else if text != ""{
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: text)!)
                my_web_view.goBack()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "from AppDelegate"? If you're simply creating a new instance in the app delegate, the @IBOutlets won't load.

Comment: I've got a function int my "AppDelegate" class. This funciton receive a notification -> a string (an url). What I need is to change the Webview url from this function.

Comment: I see that, but what I meant was how do you access the web view from your app delegate? Would probably be best if you'd add that entire function to your question.

Comment: If I understand, I can't change the WebView url from this class, Myabe I have to make event in the ViewController class to handle the nbotification and make it works :/

Comment: No, it's very possible to change the web view URL from the app delegate, just if you could post what you've done this far I'd be able to assist you.

Comment: @xoudini ->Thanks, see edit 2 :)

Comment: Hold on. How do you have an @IBOutlet in your app delegate? That can't be connected anywhere, so that's your first issue here. How are you displaying the web view, do you have a view controller with a web view?

Comment: You are the best, look at the edit 3 to see my ViewController :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are force unwrapping `url` which is not a valid URL. I would suggest adding a `guard` statement to prevent the crash if a invalid URL is created:

```
func load_url(server_url: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: server_url) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    my_web_view.loadRequest(request)
}
```

As you are obtaining the URL in the `AppDelegate` you cannot simply update the `UIWebView` from this class. You will need to call a function in the `my_web_view`'s parent class which updates the `URL`.

```
// App Delegate

var serverURL: String?

func load_url(server_url: String) {
    serverURL = server_url
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("updateWebView")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
}


// View Controller

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("updateWebView")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateWebView), name: notificationName, object: nil)

    updateWebView()
}

func updateWebView() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let serverURL = appDelegate.serverURL

    guard let url = URL(string: serverURL) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL)
    my_web_view.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the print of the url value (the string) return me : "https:// www. sortirauhavre.com/a-la-une/24-heures-kino/" I think it's a good url no ? (add spaces  in url cause stack hide me prefix of the url)

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Have you made sure that you have properly connected up your my_web_view in your storyboard? Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and determine the line on which your application crashes.

Comment: Seem's it's crashing here "let url = URL(string: server_url);"

Comment: @TomSkat See my edit. You'll now be able to check whether the URL is valid. I can confirm that the above code works for me using the address you provided

Comment: Crash here "my_web_view.loadRequest(request)" so the URL is good. (Made a mistake on the last comment ...)

Comment: You cannot reference an IBOutlet in the AppDelegate. Therefore the app crashes when attempting to load the URL using my_web_view

Comment: That's my first fear :/ Do you know how I can do that ?

Comment: You need to call a function in my_web_view parent class such as updateWebURL(withURL:) and reference the webView from there. You cannot update it in the AppDelegate

Comment: Thanks, would you like to update your answer ? I'll validate it as an answer.

Comment: Alexander MacLeod -> With your exemple, how do you pass the url true AppDelegate to ViewController ? I don't see the parameter.

Comment: You're passing the URLRequest on the final line of my example. Please remove the IBOutlet from your AppDelegate and add my example in. Make sure you change the view controller identifier and class name. The answer is there you **need** to update your code

Comment: It look's craching here "viewController.my_web_view.loadRequest(request);
" :/

Comment: @TomSkat the full answer for you

Comment: Alexander, mary me ?

Comment: make sure to add `var serverURL: String?` in your viewcontroller as well

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new instance of your view controller, or trying to duplicate the outlet, you just need to access the current instance of your view controller. You can use either:

1. A global value for the view controller, or
2. A singleton-like pattern.

Then you can access the instance from your app delegate, by calling either `myGlobalViewController.webView` or `ViewController.instance.webView`.

So, here's an example:

```
import UIKit

private var thisViewController: ViewController? // Will hold the instance.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static var instance: ViewController {
        guard let thisViewController = thisViewController else { fatalError() } // Don't do this unless you're 100% sure that you'll never access this before the instance is loaded.
        return thisViewController
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        thisViewController = self // Set the property to self.
    }
...
}
```

After this, you can access the web view from your app delegate:

```
func load_url(server_url: String){
    guard let url = URL(string: server_url) else {
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    ViewController.instance.webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot xoudini, I did'nt test your exemple cause Alexander's one did it perfectly. But thatnks a lot :D